# REST Route/Input Design

Tags: rest, url, model-view-controller, routes

I have one `Restaurant` to many `Menu`, one `Menu` to many `Category`, one `Category` to many `Item`. I'm stuck trying to find the best way to lay out the routes for these models. Here are the options I see:

1. I can flatten the routes and simply require the id of the parent model.

   - this makes the routes simple, but requires an extra input/parameter every time I want to do anything with the model.
   - `GET /menus?restaurant_id=X`
   - `POST /menus?restaurant_id=X&name=foo&description=bar`
2. I can nest all the routes within their given parent models.

   - this makes the routes long, but doesn't require any extra inputs/parameters
   - this adds unnecessary information to certain lower-level models (don't need to know restaurant directly when accessing categories/items)
   - `GET /restaurant/:restaurant_id/menus`
   - `POST /restaurant/:restaurant_id/menus?name=foo&description=bar`
   - `GET /restaurant/:restaurant_id/menus/:menu_id/categories/:category_id/items`

Is there a good standard for which to choose?

Comment: Do menus/categories/items need to be kept to a singular restaurant?

Comment: @Matt Yes. A category can belong to only one menu, a menu can belong to only one restaurant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with your very last example - I try to keep URL params to a minimum for readability and cache/proxy concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I would design it as such:

#### menus

- `POST /menus?restaurant_id=123&name=foo&description=bar`
- `GET /menus?id=890  // specific menu`
- `GET /menus?/restaurant_id=123  // many menus`

#### Items

- `POST /items?category_id=594&name=milkshake&description=vanilla`

#### more generically

- `POST /<model_of_interest>?<parent_of_model_of_interest>&<other>&<parameters>`
- `GET /<model_of_interest>?<model_of_interest_id>`

As you can see this would work for your top most and bottom most model without any additional cruft. Then validate the request and enforce access with your models which should be easily abstracted given the "only one parent" scheme you are going for (i.e. by passing `&category_id=345` to create item route, you can easily construct the rest of your object and know for certain that `345` can only ever belong to `menu_id=123` which can only even belong to `restaurant_id=...`).

This has the benefits of :

- not providing information the parent models already have
- allowing specific selection of a singular object "downwards" (e.g. give me item where `id=338`)
- allowing universal selection downwards (e.g. give me all items where `category_id=123`)